# "Image Asset" option missing in Android studio for flutter project

Tags: flutter, appicon

To change the app icon for the flutter app and to fillup, the entire circle with the custom icon looking for the "Image Asset" option but couldn't find it in the following menu?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend setting app icon via this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

If you want to do it via android studio open android folder separately:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wish that tools come back to flutter again. For now:
Close your flutter project and then open the android folder of your flutter project as an android project. It takes a while to sync. After that, you can access to New Image Asset Tool.
I know it's not the best solution, but at least, you can have your customized icons.